# Default construction for default parameters

Tags: c++, function, default-value

Premise: I'm lazy. And I don't like long lines.

Suppose you have a function that takes one parameter, and you want to give a default value for that parameter. Let's say that parameter is a `std::map`, and the default is just an empty map. The way to do it would be

```
void foo (std::map<Key,Value> the_map = std::map<Key,Value>());
```

Now, if the name of `Key` and/or `Value` is long (perhaps templated), the function declaration becomes long. It would be nice to have a way to write something like

```
void foo (std::map<Key,Value> the_map = auto);
```

Now, I know that's not the use of the keyword `auto`, but it was only to explain the concept: I don't want to double the length of an already long function declaration just because of having to write down a simple default-constructed default element. I just want to tell the compiler "look, build a default one there". Is there a way to do this? Also, does anybody feel this need too?

Note: yes, I could typedef the map type and use the short name. But I would like a different way.
Note 2: yes, I could also overload the function, so that one version of it takes no arguments and the other does. But I would like a different way.

I guess what I'm looking for is a "default default parameter"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `{}` as an *initializer-clause*, which will value-initialize the parameter.

```
void foo(std::map<K, V> the_map = {});
```

Comment: I think OP puts map there as example only, the fact that map in particular has this solution does not make this an answer in general

Comment: @Slava Can you give an example of where this wouldn't work?

Comment: hmm seems I was wrong, it works for any class with default ctor. I will +1 your answer when lock diappear (it is stupid I cannot change my vote if answer haven't changed)

Comment: YES! This is what I was looking for. I tried it and it works. But it looks like it would fail in case of explicit default constructor. I guess in that case there's no way around, uh?

Comment: @bartgol I'm not sure about this. In the current wording of the standard, this actually does work when the default constructor is explicit. However, there is a defect report about this issue (and I don't really understand what's going on). If you want a definitive answer, post to the std-discussion mailing list. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1518